# perform segue to view controller behind tab and nav-controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have issues accessing a view controller that is sitting behind a TAB and NAV controller.

I'm able to access the first VC (see code below) but I can not access the fourth VC.

```
         SenderVC----->TabBarVC-⎜----NavVC----FirstVC
                                ⎜----NavVC----SecondVC
                                ⎜----NavVC----ThirdVC
                                ⎜----NavVC----FourthVC
```

What do I wrong?

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "segueVC0") {
        let tabVC = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let navVC = tabVC.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        let destVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as! FirstVC  // ==> this transition is working

    } else if (segue.identifier == "segueVC4") {
        let tabVC = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let navVC = tabVC.viewControllers![4] as! UINavigationController
        let destVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as! FourthVC  // ==> this transition is NOT working !!!

    } else {
        print ("wrong segue ID")
    }
}
```

Comment: try this way navVC.topviewcontrolle as! FourthVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi here i got the instance of Fourth VC

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("ViewController - buttonTapped()")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "seg4", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "seg1" {
        let tabVC = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let navVC = tabVC.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        let destVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as! Seq1  // ==> this transition is working

        print(destVC)

    }
    else if segue.identifier == "seg4"{
        let tabVC = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let navVC = tabVC.viewControllers![3] as! UINavigationController
        let destVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as! Seq4  // ==> this transition is working
        destVC.hello()
        print(destVC)
    }

}
```

}

class Seq1: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

class Seq2: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}
class Seq3: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}
class Seq4: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Hello")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func hello() {
    print("Hello")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Note: The tabbar controller will always shows FirstVC. Because it is the default selection. If you want, change the selectedIndex = 3

Comment: thanks you for the answer. But it is not working. The function Hello in seg4 is called but the transition goes to controller 1 (index 0 although in the code index 3 is set). Any sugestions ? PS: the segues in the story board go from ViewController to TabBar Controller (seg1) and  ViewController to TabBar Controller (seg4) . Is it possible to send you my project ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Create custom class for UITabBarController and then get the destination like this

```
let tabVC = segue.destination as! HomeTabBarcController
  let navVC = tabVC.viewControllers![4] as! UINavigationController
  let destVC = navVC.topViewController as! FourthVC
```

It works for me. Hope it will work for you

Comment: NITHI CHAN, Nazmul Hasan, thanks for the feedback but it is not woking. Maybe I didn't explain the setup correctly. Please have a look at my problem description. I added some text that explains my setup better. Thank you from any suggestion.